# div following floating left element does not keep on its right

Tags: jquery, css

Please take a look at [this page](http://iloop.it/iloop-nano-10mm.asp): clicking on the orange cart badge always added contents on its right (since badge is `float: left`).

Now I messed with something and added content ends up **under** the badge at the end of the animation and I can't figure why!

I'm using Firebug too but it's about an hour I'm diggin in it with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `h2` tag. Headers are block-level elements that do not float by default. You would have to add `display-inline` explicitly to that header.

Comment: You put me on the right path! I recently added the `clear: both` to headings but I didn't remember it, thank you.